# How to add access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

How to add access token for this URL http://graph.facebook.com/?id=#{checked_url}&access_token=#{access_token} instead of http://graph.facebook.com/?id=#{checked_url}

```
module SocialShares
  class Facebook < Base
    def shares!
      response = RestClient.get(url, params: {
        fields: 'share'
      })
      json_response = JSON.parse(response)

      if json_response['share']
        json_response['share']['share_count'] || 0
      else
        0
      end
    end

  private

    def url
      "http://graph.facebook.com/?id=#{checked_url}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add access token to

```
 "http://graph.facebook.com/?id=#{checked_url}#{access_token}"
private
  def access_token
    youracesstoken
  end
```